# C# Recursive lambda expression in extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, lambda

Please consider the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bll {
    public static class Extensions {

        public static IQueryable<Sys.EntityModels.BfxProject> CompleteProject( this Sys.EntityModels.BfxEntities context ) {
            return context.BfxProjects
                .Include( x => x.BfxFiles.Select( f => f.BfxSecurity ) );
        }
    }
}
```

BfxProjects can have nested BfxProjects. I would like the CompleteProject extension method to recursively return even any nested BfxProjects. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can't. Consider the possibility in SQL. This requires Recursive CTE to do in SQL Server, and that isn't supported in EF.

Comment: Oh ok. Ultimately, I still need to return all BfxProjects and all nested BfxProjects... what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can just get all `BfxProject`s. If the table is small...All of the relationships/properties will be properly bound.